# Выпадающий список с элементами связанной таблицы

Tags: access, html

Есть 2 таблицы:

1. "Склад" с полями "код", "название"
2. "Продукция" с полями "название", "количество", "кодСклада"

поля Склад.Код и Продукция.КодСклада связаны отношением один-ко-многим.

Как создать выпадающий список (для поля "КодСклада" формы таблицы "продукция") в котором вместо числового обозначения кода склада были бы их названия? Как атрибут value HTML тега `<select><option value="КодСклада">Названия складов</option></select>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прописать в rowsource комбобокса эту таблицу (или основанный на таблице запрос). Обратите внимание, что controlsource остается тем же числом. Поскольку boundcolumn по умолчанию 1, то первым полем выводите ключ, а чтобы в свернутом виде отображалось текстовое значение, впишите в columnwidths столько нулей через точку с запятой, сколько столбцов хотите пропустить.